# How to instantiate a class without knowing its package?

Tags: java, reflection

I have an Eclipse project (MainProject) and it references another Eclipse project (ReferencedProject). MainProject also references a JAR file (ReferencedJar). This ReferencedJar's file name is known. I also know there is a class (ReferencedClass) in ReferencedJar, but I don't know in what package ReferencedClass is because the package path is not known beforehand.

I need to instantiate ReferencedClass in ReferencedProject using reflection. How can I do this? And will the solution be okay when the project is packaged to a its standalone jar outside Eclipse?

The reason for this question is; The ReferencedJar is file generated by a modeller application. It generates java classes for your model and puts them into ReferencedJar. The user can choose which package the classes it generates will be put into. But the class names are always the same. MainProject is project that will include this generated jar, but ReferencedProject (a framework) also needs to instantiate a class in this generated jar. Hope this makes the question more clear.

Thanks in advance

Edit: Actually I have an idea but don't know how to implement it. Because I know the name of ReferencedJar file, I could access it on runtime and check all the classes it contains. Then I can find the matching class by name comparison. But how can I access the ReferencedJar on runtime?

Comment: If you're in control of the process, and some kind of configuration file in a known  location which lists the fully qualified ReferencedClass name

Comment: Sadly, I am not. I can't modify the code of Modeller application.

Answer (score 2):

As long as the class you need is in the class path, you can get a reference to it by invoking [`Class.forName(String className)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29)

```
String className = "WhatEver";
String packageName = "some.package";
Class<?> c = Class.forName(packageName + "." + className);
```

If you don't know the package name, however, and there's no way to get it from a configuration file, I would recommend using a library like [reflections](https://code.google.com/p/reflections/) to scan the class path and find the relevant class.

Comment: Reflections library web site says it get all resources matching matching a regular expression. I think that should solve my problem, but honestly I don't prefer to use a whole library for this task. Yet again, I will try this out if I cannot find a simpler solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can not instantiate a class you if do not know its package